# Reading particular word by its position in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have following lines in a file:

Displaying 5 of **17** -- All country members

Displaying 0 of **0** -- All country members

Displaying 15 of **417** -- All country members

Displaying 134 of **4890** -- All country members

In my script condition, i may get any line from the above.
I want to fetch only the bold number.

Is there any way to fetch the 4th word of a line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Split() to get an array of the " " separated chunks of the line and access the fourth element by accessing it with its (zero-based) index 3.

demo:

```
>> WScript.Echo Split("Displaying 134 of 4890 -- All country members")(3)
>>
4890
>>
```